# Ordering collection within group partitions using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have simple type `Question`:

```
public class Question
{
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

While I have a list of questions, I need to filter them along list of tags (called filters). The questions which have the most tags matched by the filters list, should be placed higher in the result collection. I wrote expression for that:

```
public IList<Question> GetSimiliar(IList<Questions> all, string[] filters)
{
    var questions = all.Select(
                        x => new 
                               { 
                                  MatchedTags = x.Tags
                                                 .Count(tag => filters.Contains(tag)), 
                                  Question = x 
                               })
                       .Where(x => x.MatchedTags > 0)
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.MatchedTags)
                       .Select(x => x.Question);

    return questions.ToList();
}
```

Now I need a support for such situation, where I have more than one question with the same quantity of matched tags. Such questions should be further sorted by creation date (from newest to oldest).

Example of what I want:

filter: tags = [a,b,c]

collection of questions to be filtered:

1. q1 { tags = [a], created = 1939 }
2. q2 { tags = [b], created = 1945 }
3. q3 { tags = [a,b,c], created = 1800 }
4. q4 { tags = [a,b], created = 2012 }
5. q5 { tags = [z], created = 1999 }

result - the sorted collection:

1. q3
2. q4
3. q2
4. q1

How to do that using linq ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I need a support for such situation, where I have more than one question with the same quantity of matched tags. Such questions should be **further sorted** by creation date (from newest to oldest).

Use `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending` to further sort your query.  Use these methods to break ties in prior ordering.

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.MatchedTags)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Question.Created)
.Select(x => x.Question);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [101 Linq Samples page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) has a [nested grouping example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea#Nested).  This sample uses group by to partition a list of each customer's orders, first by year, and then by month:

```
public void Linq43() 
{ 
    List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList(); 

    var customerOrderGroups = 
        from c in customers 
        select 
            new 
            { 
                c.CompanyName, 
                YearGroups = 
                    from o in c.Orders 
                    group o by o.OrderDate.Year into yg 
                    select 
                        new 
                        { 
                            Year = yg.Key, 
                            MonthGroups = 
                                from o in yg 
                                group o by o.OrderDate.Month into mg 
                                select new { Month = mg.Key, Orders = mg } 
                        } 
            }; 

    ObjectDumper.Write(customerOrderGroups, 3); 
}
```